# How can I test for Groovy constructors in Spock Unit test with 100% code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock, cobertura

My question is: I am new to Spock testing, and am trying to get 100% code coverage on this User Class. To get me started, can someone help me figure out how to test the constructor. What I currently have is not covering it using the cobertura plugin. Also, if someone is knowledgeable about Spock + Cobertura, maybe you could shed some light on what I'm doing wrong, and some pointers for further testing.

I have a class that represents a user:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

class User implements Serializable {
    String email
    byte[] photo

    static hasMany = [lineups: Lineup]

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    User(String username, String password) {
        this()
        this.username = username
        this.password = password
    }

    @Override
    int hashCode() {
        username?.hashCode() ?: 0
    }

    @Override
    boolean equals(other) {
        is(other) || (other instanceof User && other.username == username)
    }


    Set<SecRole> getAuthorities() {
        SecUserSecRole.findAllBySecUser(this)*.secRole
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false

        email(unique: true, blank: false, nullable: true)  // needs to be moved to account
        photo(nullable:true, maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2 /* 2MB */)
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    String toString() {
        return id + ": " + email + " " + username
    }
}
```

Then I have a Spock Unit Test: (not all my code is here, but just for the examples that I'm requesting info on...

```
@TestFor(User)
class UserSpec extends Specification {
    User user

    def setup() {
        user = new User(
            username: "fredflintstone",
            password: "Wilma1",
            enabled: true).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

    }

    def cleanup() {
        user = null
    }

    // Constructor tests
    void "test to check constructor works"() {
        when:
        mockForConstraintsTests(User, [user])

        expect:
        user.validate()
        user != null
        user.username != null
        user.password != null
    }

    void "test #hashCode works"() {
        setup:

        mockForConstraintsTests(User, [user])

        expect:
        user.username.hashCode() != null

    }

}
```

Comment: 100% test coverage can be overly difficult and not all that meaningful, especially with a language like Groovy where there may be other factors at play. Generally, if you can hit 80-90% without too much pain you are doing well... beyond that you can have diminishing returns.

Comment: 100% test coverage usually makes me think people have concentrating on achieving 100%, more than they have considered what and why they are testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First

You really don't need to (and shouldn't waste time) testing code that can only break if something in the JVM breaks.  Testing basic getters and setters doesn't benefit your code, the logic is too simple to break.  Consequently, 100% test coverage is a poor test goal.  What you should aim for is...

1. Maintainable tests

   - They likely will go months without being looked at
   - The next developer to touch them is unlikely to be you
2. A consistent test format across all test classes

   - Spend more time comprehending the test, less time 'reading' it
3. A test format that allows you to understand test coverage at a glance

   - You shouldn't need an external tool to tell you when you've tested enough
4. 100% coverage of class' methods (excluding methods with trivial logic)
5. Reasonably complete coverage of each method's inputs

   - Each int parameter should at least test the inner and outer extremes of expected values, 0, a negative number, and a positive number
   - Ideally every combination of possible test inputs would be tested if multiple parameters are involved
   - Realistically there's plenty of room to trim the amount of inputs for testing

This approach may lead to some overlap in the eyes of a code coverage tool, but it will respond better to changing conditions and get unfamiliar developers up to speed in as short a time as possible.

### Second

Since you're new to Spock let's talk about it for a bit. The best thing about it is how easy it is to parameterize your tests.  Here is my approach to test scoping at a unit test level (functional tests aren't always as straight forward). You'll probably notice some overlap with the testing goals I outlined above.

- 1 Spec Class per class testing (User.class in your case)
- 1 Test per method

  - Each unique non-empty constructor counts as a method
- 1 Test per method that can throw an exception

  - Because testing logic for exceptions typically doesn't complement normal testing logic
- 1 Test iteration per input combination

This approach requires a healthy understanding of the where: block, but has a number of benefits. It's easy to see what methods have been tested, it's easy to see which inputs have been tested for each method, it greatly encourages test independence, it encourages code reuse, helper method reuse can be cleanly and predictably scoped across many levels (a single method's test, the entire Spec Class, multiple Spec Classes), and a few other things that I can't think of at this moment.

---

Now onto your test case. If your constructor doesn't do anything other than act as a giant setter method, you shouldn't spend much time on it.  One test case to make sure nothing catastrophic happens is plenty; I went overboard here to give you an example of how I write Spock tests. I like the list of maps approach because it keeps each test iteration tightly coupled and allows for optional variables and other flexibilities. If you want to learn more about parameterized tests in Spock, here's the [official documentation](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html).

```
@Unroll(iteration.testName)
void "testing the constructor"() {
    setup:
        user = new User(
            username: iteration.username,
            password: iteration.password,
            enabled: iteration.enabled).save(failOnError: true, flush: true) 
    when:
        mockForConstraintsTests(User, [user])

    expect:
        user != null
        user.validate() == iteration.valid
        user.username == iteration.username
        user.password == iteration.password
        user.enabled == iteration.enabled
        user.username.hashCode() != null // May need modification

    where: 
        iteration << [

        [testName: "Testing a normal enabled object"
        username: "fredflintstone"
        password: "Wilma1"
        enabled: true,
        valid: true ],

        [testName: "Testing a normal disabled object"
        username: "fredflintstone"
        password: "Wilma1"
        enabled: false,
        valid: true ],

        [testName: "Testing a disabled user, null name"
        username: null
        password: "Wilma1"
        enabled: false,
        valid: false ],

        [testName: "Testing a disabled user, empty name"
        username: ""
        password: "Wilma1"
        enabled: false,
        valid: false ],
        ]
}
```

---

If hashCode() involves more than just one parameter that method should probably get its own test that uses a Stub to setup only the part of User.class needed to test the method.

---

**Personal opinion warning!**
As much fun as coverage plugins are, they distract and disguise some major flaws inherent to the typical jUnit approach to unit testing.

If you have 100 tests, one for each input permutation possible for every method, does your 100% code coverage score matter? Sort of. You have some measure of proof that everything is covered, but you likely can't trace that coverage back to any individual test. Giving you a small measure of comprehension without the ability to make ready use of it. Code coverage tools aren't *bad*. A good test scoping methodology like I outlined above can help you gain more utility out of your test metrics. They just can too easily become a crutch for poor testing methodologies.